# On a button click, redirect to a new page using href and also invoke a javascript function using onclick at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, button

So, I am building this web application using Python and Flask. I have a button on my html page that redirects to a new page when clicked using href. I am trying to see if I can invoke a javascript function using onclick at the same time using the same button. If I do not put href and do not redirect, onclick works fine and gives me what I am looking for but if if I use href, onclick stops working. The button will redirect to a new page but onclick will not do anything/suppress.

My code is here:

```
fieldset>
<p>Checkout freshly discovered hosts: <a href="{{ url_for('discoveredHostsList') }}"><input type="button" id="Button1" onclick="listDiscoveredHosts()" value="List"></button></a></p>
<p id="showData1"></p> <br>
```

How do I make that href and onclick work with that same button? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Don't tag python and Flask if the issue is with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the end of your "onclick" function:

```js
window.location.href = "https://url.com";
```